# Android Studio "Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed."

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Was just doing my android dev training after days not doing it, and then when i tried to run the program i've made several days ago which was running fine, but now it wont even run. i didnt even change a thing when opening it again.
i tried both virtual device (pixel 3a) and my real device (xiaomi redmi note 10) and both doesnt work.

this is the error i got

```
10/18 16:38:29: Launching 'app' on No Devices.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\Daffa\Documents\Coding\Android Studio\MyFlexibleFragment\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --full --dont-kill --skip-verification -S 3593865' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package''
Retry
```

I even created a fresh hello world program and it still wont work.
halp, im just a trainee at this point and this bug is blocking my study

Answer (score 0):

A) Please try to restart your real device after enabling Developer Mode, also remove the pre-installed version of your app from the device.

If this wasn't enough..

B)

1. Choose Run -> edit configurations.
2. Navigate to Your app Module then -> General -> Installation Options -> Install Flags.
3. Add flags -r -t in install flags.

PS: These flags mean adb install -r -t [apk path]

[Check this screenshot, please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJNFF.jpg)

Hopefully this will do the trick for you as it did for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you for your answer but my friend told me to do a cold boot on the virtual android, and then as i do it i deleted my project application in that device, and it fixed the problem somehow